# difference between newLine() and carriage return("\r")

Tags: java

What is the difference between `newLine()` and carriage return ("\r")?
Which one is best to use?

```
File f = new File(strFileGenLoc);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f, false));
rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from jpdata");
while ( rs.next() ) 
{
    bw.write(rs.getString(1)==null? "":rs.getString(1));
    bw.newLine();
}
```

Comment: Which `newLine()` are you referring to?

Comment: @ skaffman.. please see the above code i am using.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming you mean this:

```
public static String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

`newLine` is environment agnostic `\r` isn't.

So `newLine` will give you `\r\n` on windows but `\n` on another environment.

However, you shouldn't use this in a JTextArea and println will work fine with just `\n` on windows.

**Edit now that I've seen the code and your comment**

In your situation. I think you should use your own constant - `\r\n`

```
  File f = new File(strFileGenLoc);
  BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f, false));
  rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from jpdata");
  while ( rs.next() ) {
    bw.write(rs.getString(1)==null? "":rs.getString(1));
    bw.write("\\r\\n");
  }
```

Comment: . i am creating text file in unix environment using java code.
       and transmitting the file to client ,but from thier side they
       need carriage return in text file. which one i have to use
       newLine() or carriage return ("\r")

Comment: I would use "\r\n" as that will display properly on  windows and most unix text editors.

Answer (score 9):

In the old days of ASR-33 teletypes (and, later, dot-matrix printers with travelling print-heads), the CR literally returned the carriage to the left, as in a typewriter, and the LF advanced the paper. The machinery could overlap the operations if the CR came before the LF, so that's why the newline character was always CR-LF, i.e. \r\n. If you got it back to front it took much longer to print. Unix was the first (only?) system to adopt just \n as the standard line separator. DOS/Windows didn't.

Answer (score 1):

> Write a line separator. The line
>   separator string is defined by the
>   system property line.separator, and is
>   not necessarily a single newline
>   ('\n') character.

source: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. The customer needs the carriage return. So he has to write it.

Answer (score 0):

the major  newLine(`\n`) and carriage return (`\r`) is :

new line(`\n`) & carriage return (`\r`) both r escape sequence in java..

new line(`\n`):

when ever `\n` is found in executable statements,the `JVM` splits the line into 2 parts from where we placed `\n` (escape sequence).. 
example :

```
println("Stackover\nflow");
```

output:

```
Stackover // here the line got split into 2 lines because of "\n"   
flow
```

carriage return (`\r`):

the data or character placed after the `\r` get overtire with the previous characters present in the same line ...

example :

```
println("Stackover\rflow"); 
output:
flow  // here Statckover is overtired  because of "\r"
```

Comment: The JVM doesn't split anything. The *line* is *already split,* by virtue of the newline. The *device* it's being printed *on* may or may not behave as you've described. The JVM plays precisely no part in any of it. Too much misinformation. -1

Answer (score 0):

On Windows platforms, the line separator is CRLF (carriage return / line feed), which is "\r\n". On Unix platforms, it's just LF, "\n". Traditionally, on Apple platforms it has been just CR, "\r".