# Java - What does "\n" mean?

Tags: java

I had created a 2-dimensional array in Java and I was looking for a way to print it out on the console so that I could confirm that the stuff I was making was correct. I found some code online that performed this task for me, but I had a question about what a particular bit of the code meant.

```
int n = 10;
int[][] Grid = new int[n][n];

//some code dealing with populating Grid

void PrintGrid() {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            System.out.print(Grid[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

What does "\n" do? I tried searching on Google, but since it's such a small bit of code I couldn't find much.

Comment: Did you really searched [using your title](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=What+is+%5Cn+in+Java&rlz=2C1CHWA_enIN0536IN0536&oq=What+is+%5Cn+in+Java&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3002j0&sourceid=chrome&espvd=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)?

Comment: Although I should said this is not bring much value on StackOverflow with this kind of question, but then we got all simple questions in one place anyway.

Comment: Did you try to remove the line (put it in comment) and see what the difference was in the output?

Comment: I don't understand why this kind of questions gets too many answers. I mean, it's too simple if just one person answers is enough. Eight answers and counting...

Comment: Yeah... I messed up. I Google searched "/n" instead of "\n". Thanks for the responses anyway.

Comment: @RohitJain - Problem is, if he just Googles for `"\n"` he gets only one relevant answer in the first 50 hits, and that could be easily overlooked.  The odds are better if you throw in "Java".

Answer (score 44):

Its is a new line

```
Escape Sequences
Escape Sequence Description
\t  Insert a tab in the text at this point.
\b  Insert a backspace in the text at this point.
\n  Insert a newline in the text at this point.
\r  Insert a carriage return in the text at this point.
\f  Insert a formfeed in the text at this point.
\'  Insert a single quote character in the text at this point.
\"  Insert a double quote character in the text at this point.
\\  Insert a backslash character in the text at this point.
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html

From the Java Language Specification.

```
EscapeSequence:
\ b (backspace BS, Unicode \u0008)
\ t (horizontal tab HT, Unicode \u0009)
\ n (linefeed LF, Unicode \u000a)
\ f (form feed FF, Unicode \u000c)
\ r (carriage return CR, Unicode \u000d)
\ " (double quote ", Unicode \u0022)
\ ' (single quote ', Unicode \u0027)
\ \ (backslash \, Unicode \u005c)
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6

Comment: And note that in Java these escape sequences are valid in literal strings surrounded by "double quotes" and in individual characters literals surrounded by 'single quotes'.  That is, `'\n'` is one character (numerically 0x0A), even though you type it as two characters.

Comment: I was wondering, in Linux shell why `\n` and `\\n` both give a new line, where `\\\n` gives literally `\n`? how does the shell deal with that and what happens behind the scenes?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin the \\n should be back slash + `n` and \\\n should be back slash + new line.

Comment: Is there any documentation on what `\n` ***is***? *"Insert a newline in the text at this point"* Which Unicode character is *"newline"*?  U+000D? Nope, that's `CARRIAGE RETURN` U+000A? Nope, that's [`LINE FEED`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000a/index.htm). Does it insert U+000D? U+000A? U+000D+U+000A? U+0085? U+2028? U+2029? Is it an implementation detail that is up to the JRE you're running on? Does it change depending if you're running on Windows, Mac, or Unix?

Comment: @IanBoyd It's a line feed, but I can't find anything official which says that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260126/what-are-the-differences-between-char-literals-n-and-r-in-java

Comment: @IanBoyd Actually there is this. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6

Answer (score 8):

```
\n
```

This means insert a newline in the text at this point.

Just example

```
System.out.println("hello\nworld");
```

Output:

```
hello
world
```

Answer (score 5):

```
\n
```

That means a new line is printed.

As a side note there is no need to write  that extra line . There is an built in  inbuilt  function there.

```
 println()  //prints the content in new line
```

[Learn more from docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)

Comment: I don't think so. I found `void println("...")` to be much slower than `void print("..." + "\n")` for some reason. This means that it can really slow down your project if you print out a lot.

Comment: Sorry - I was not done with the coment and posted it on accident.

Comment: In ideal cases..i remove all system.out.println statements in production codes.

Answer (score 5):

(as per http://java.sun.com/...ex/Pattern.html)

The backslash character ('`\`') serves to introduce escaped constructs, as defined in the table above, as well as to quote characters that otherwise would be interpreted as unescaped constructs. Thus the expression `\\` matches a single backslash and { matches a left brace.

Other examples of usage :

```
\\ The backslash character<br>
\t The tab character ('\u0009')<br>
\n The newline (line feed) character ('\u000A')<br>
\r The carriage-return character ('\u000D')<br>
\f The form-feed character ('\u000C')<br>
\a The alert (bell) character ('\u0007')<br>
\e The escape character ('\u001B')<br>
\cx The control character corresponding to x <br>
```

Answer (score 1):

`\n` is an escape character for strings that is replaced with the new line object. Writing `\n` in a string that prints out will print out a new line instead of the `\n`

[Java Escape Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367322/what-are-all-the-escape-characters-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

In the specific case of the code example from the original question, the

```
System.out.print("\n");
```

is there to move to a new line between incrementing i.

So the first print statement prints all of the elements of Grid[0][j].  When the innermost for loop has completed, the "\n" gets printed and then all of the elements of Grid[1][j] are printed on the next line, and this is repeated until you have a 10x10 grid of the elements of the 2-dimensional array, Grid.

Answer (score 0):

\n is add a new line.

Please note java has method
 System.out.println("Write text here");

Notice the difference:

Code:

```
System.out.println("Text 1");
System.out.println("Text 2");
```

Output:

```
Text 1
Text 2
```

Code:

```
System.out.print("Text 1");
System.out.print("Text 2");
```

Output:

```
Text 1Text 2
```