# How can I insert some text into a textarea using JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, textarea

I have two textareas - one for pasting some text in it, the other is for inserting words from the first textarea after doubleclicking on them. How can I make it happen?

I've already achieved some result on the following case: 
1.Paste some text into textarea
2.Double click on the word from textarea
3.See how this word appears in a div with ul inside. The word adds as a li.
See the code of the case:

```
//html block
<textarea name="" id="text" cols="30" rows="10" ondblclick="copyPaste()" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur minus iure suscipit quam expedita? Sed minus laboriosam natus quaerat autem enim accusantium, architecto officiis aliquam pariatur. Adipisci provident tenetur velit!</textarea>
    <div id="wordList" class="wordListclass">
        <ul id="myList">
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

```
//js block for copy-pasting words after doubleclick on the text from the texarea with id ='text'
"use strict";

function copyPaste(){
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    console.log(selection.toString());
    var node = document.createElement("LI");               
var selectionWithButton =  selection;
var textnode = document.createTextNode(selectionWithButton);      
node.appendChild(textnode);                             
document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);   
}
```

Now I need to get rid of  and add the second textarea. I want to see how words after doublclicking on the text from the first textarea appear in the second textarea. Important note - they should have the following structure:

word1

word2

word3

without html tags, because after I see the list of these words in the second textarea I want to insert them into a database, so html tags (as in the code I provided) would be undesirable.
Replacing div element with textarea just didn't work, unfortunately.
Thanks everyone for reading and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you just want to paste the selected word in the second textarea instead of the list.

For that, you can simply append the text using the property `value` of the textarea.

In order for the text to apear on different lines, you can use `\n` which is a character that insert a new line. You can find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19009007/7810737) about the escape sequence.

Your function could look like this:

```js
function copyPaste(){
    // trim() is used here to remove the whitespace at the end of the word when you dblClick on a word
    const selection = window.getSelection().toString().trim();
    const textarea2 = document.getElementById("pasteTextarea");
    if(!textarea2.value) {
        // Don't add a new line when the textarea is empty
     textarea2.value = selection;
    }
  else {
     textarea2.value += `\n${selection}`;    
    }
}
```

```html
<textarea name="" id="text" cols="30" rows="10" ondblclick="copyPaste()" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur minus iure suscipit quam expedita? Sed minus laboriosam natus quaerat autem enim accusantium, architecto officiis aliquam pariatur. Adipisci provident tenetur velit!</textarea>

<textarea name="" id="pasteTextarea" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    const myList = document.querySelector("div#wordList ul#myList") // Get the list

    function copyPaste(){
        let textAreaValue = document.querySelector("textarea#text").value //get the written text in textarea
        myList.innerHTML += `<li> ${textAreaValue} </li>` //put the "textAreaValue" in the list
    }
```

Something like this?