# Problems reading from System.in.read()

Tags: java

I just learned that when pressing enter in response to a `System.in.read()`, the following characters are put into the console buffer, `\r\n`. So when I input the following `1` into the terminal and press enter, the computer reads that statement as `1\r\n`. So shouldn't `System.out.println("hello")` be excuted twice? Because `choice` will store the value `1`. And then, `"hello"` will be printed. Then, `ignore` will hold the value `\r`. Then, the control will be given `while(ignore != '\n')` loop. Then, `ignore` will hold the value `\n`. And then, `"hello"` will be printed. And now that `ignore = \n`, the code will break out of the loop?

```
class HelpClassDemo {
  public static void main(String args[])
    throws java.io.IOException {
    char choice, ignore;

    for(;;) {
      do {
        System.out.println("Help on:");
        System.out.println("  1. if");
        System.out.println("  2. switch");
        System.out.println("  3. for");
        System.out.println("  4. while");
        System.out.println("  5. do-while");
        System.out.println("  6. break");
        System.out.println("  7. continue\n");
        System.out.print("Choose one (q to quit): ");

        choice = (char) System.in.read();

        do {
          ignore = (char) System.in.read();
          System.out.println("hello"); 
        } while(ignore != '\n');
      } while(choice < '1' | choice > '7' & choice != 'q');

      if(choice == 'q') break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: where did you learn that? and what makes you think it is true? and when you actually tried, and logged the value of each result of a call to `read`, what did you get? what is your question?

Comment: Why are you using `System.in.read()` ? You should use [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think whether the code will have `\r` (carriage return), `\n` (new line) or both `\r\n` depends upon the platform.

I ran your code on a windows machine and it did print `hello` twice.

You may want to check the machine you are using and the line separator defined for that environment. Please refer  [What are the differences between char literals '\n' and '\r' in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260126/what-are-the-differences-between-char-literals-n-and-r-in-java) for further details.

```
Help on:
  1. if
  2. switch
  3. for
  4. while
  5. do-while
  6. break
  7. continue

Choose one (q to quit): 1
choice1
hello
hello
```