# XPages to create .txt File via SSJS

Tags: export, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I need to create a text file with SSJS. I get data from a document then i will write all data in a text file. I tried to some solution which i find searching on the internet but I could not get result I needed.

Regards 
Any Suggestion is appreciated
Cumhur Ata

UPDATE:

```
writer.endDocument();
facesContext.responseComplete();
writer.close();
```

[image: Screenshot of confirmation]

**UPDATE 2 :**

```
<xp:button value="Create TXT File" id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:var con = facesContext.getExternalContext();
var response:com.ibm.xsp.webapp.XspHttpServletResponse = con.getResponse();
response.setContentType("text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
response.setDateHeader("Expires", -1);
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"file.txt\"" );
var strEntr = "\n";
var str1 = "TXTV2[] \n";
str1 +=  "NUMBER|CLIENT_ID|START_DATE|END_DATE|\n";
str1 += "UNITS|DESCRIPTION|CLASSIFICATION|"+strEntr;
str1 += "[]";
response.getOutputStream().write(str1.getBytes());
facesContext.responseComplete();   }]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
```

Comment: You're not telling us, *what* you have tried so far. Try to be more specific: what are the results you're getting so far, and why aren't they meeting your expactations?

Comment: I tried this kind of samples
https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/NotesStream_sample_JavaScript_code_for_XPages

Comment: Again: what kind of result did you get from that sample code, error messages? Faulty text file? Which one of the samples from the wiki did you try, and what was it that you didn't like about its result?

Comment: I used the code Lars sent. but the only problem is when i try to run with this code It asks to save file. I need to save the file without confirmation in to my hard drive. I added what i tried to save it automatically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This example will download the content of a String as a txt-File.

Hope that helps.

```
var textBuffer = "some text here";
var con = facesContext.getExternalContext();
var response:com.ibm.xsp.webapp.XspHttpServletResponse = con.getResponse();
response.setContentType("text/plain");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
response.setDateHeader("Expires", -1);
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"file.txt\"" );
response.getOutputStream().write(textBuffer.getBytes());
facesContext.responseComplete();
```

Comment: Do you know How to go next line below just like Enter key does it.

Comment: You can add "\n" to the String to start a new Line.

Comment: I tried and it did not work for me :( 
I added my button with code into my question. I think I miss something :(

Comment: Maybe a \r helps. Hava a look here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260126/what-are-the-differences-between-char-literals-n-and-r-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize Java code in your SSJS.

```
importPackage(Java class) // whole Java class name with package !!!not string
var tmp = new ImportedClassName()
tmp.run() // run all logic
```

Hope I help. Best regards.