# text file upload line by line getting "\r"

Tags: javascript

hello everyone I want to get the data line by line I have done it successfully now I want line by line plus word by word so I used this code

```
 var openFile = function(event) {
        var input = event.target;

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(){
          var text = reader.result;
          var node = document.getElementById('output');
            node.innerText = text;
              var lines = this.result.split('\n');
         for(var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++){
            console.log(lines[line].split(" "));
          }
        };
        reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
      };
```

the result is shocking in the console I am getting \r with the string
[image]

Comment: `var lines = this.result.split('\r\n');`

Comment: how do you know

Comment: The lines of Windows text files have both a \r (carriage **r**eturn) and a \n (**n**ewline) character at the end. You need to split using \r\n to get just the text of each line.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not *split('\r\n')* as different OS'es use different character to end line.

From what I read in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260126/what-are-the-differences-between-char-literals-n-and-r-in-java), Windows uses *'\r\n'*, MacOS uses *'\r'* and Unix uses *'\n'*.

Since this is JavaScript, I assume you need an answer to cover most, if not all, possibilities.
So, for a complete answer, I believe you should do the following.

```
let lines='';
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Win')!=-1)
    lines = this.result.split('\r\n');
else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Mac')!=-1)
    lines = this.result.split('\r');
else
    lines = this.result.split('\n');
```