# Keeping String formatting while writting to a file JAVA

Tags: java, formatting, filewriter

Trying to preserve my string formatting.
When I open my .txt file, everything just gets written to one line.

```
String page = t.toString(); //this is my formatting String
        String fileName = t.getSymbol(); //just helps me name the file (not important)
        File file = new File("C:/Users/user1234212/desktop/folder1" + fileName + ".txt"); //not important here
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs(); // also not important
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile()); //why does this reformat page ?
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(page);
            bw.close();
```

RESULT SHOULD BE:
title:
other info:

Name:  joe john

title:  person

Summary...
Joe john is a person.

Question...
no question

Answer...

^ This is the String "page"

Comment: What's `page`?  What's the expected results compared to the actual?

Comment: what is t.toString(); ?? You should look there.

Comment: Nothing there should reformat anything.  I think `t.toString()` might do the reformatting.  Otherwise, show us with a sample string how it gets reformatted.

Comment: Try using :- PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);  pw.print(page);  pw.flush(); pw.close();

Comment: t.toString() does the formatting correctly. If I use println(page) the text is correctly formatted.

Comment: @xTehOnex using pw.print(page) doesn't work is it? does pw.println(page) work? Is your issue resolved>?

Comment: @ManjunathAnand I don't understand.. what is PrintWriter pw replacing? could you post this as a code snipet?

Comment: @ManjunathAnand BufferedWriter class does not have println. PrintWriter has

Comment: @KickButtowski yes correct. I was referring to println with respect to my earlier comment above

Comment: @ManjunathAnand k cool cuz the op seems very confused

Comment: @KickButtowski yes thats correct. I too got confused when xTehOnex commented above that doing println(page) , the text got formatted

Comment: @ManjunathAnand what can I say?

Answer (score 0):

**If I understand your issue**

you have to use

The `java.io.BufferedWriter.newLine()`: Writes a line separator. The line separator string is defined by the system property line.separator, and is not necessarily a single newline `('\n')` character..

if you want to each content of your data file be written in each line, you must call `newLine()`

source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine()

I found this from a post

> newLine is environment agnostic \r isn't.
>
> So newLine will give you \r\n on windows but \n on another environment

source: [difference between newLine() and carriage return("\r")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307747/difference-between-newline-and-carriage-return-r)

Difference between `\r` and `\n`

> The difference is not Java-specific, but platform specific.
>   Historically UNIX-like OSes have used \n as newline character, some
>   other deprecated OSes have used \r and Windows OSes have employed
>   \r\n.

Source: [What are the differences between char literals '\n' and '\r' in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260126/what-are-the-differences-between-char-literals-n-and-r-in-java/9260253#9260253)

Comment: Is there another Java writing method that would allow me to write multiple lines with a single String?

Comment: what do you mean? can you clarify that? this is the only method that gives you the new line

Comment: I have a String that uses "\r" to make multiple lines, and I want to print that String to the .txt file saving the formatting (spacing).

Comment: @xTehOnex I found this link. take a look at it and lemme know http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307747/difference-between-newline-and-carriage-return-r

Comment: It seems like it may be easier to use a different method in order to retain my line separated text. Unfortunately I cannot share my entire code for you to look at.