# Why System.out.print("\r"message) is printing new lines?

Tags: java, eclipse, utf-8, carriage-return, system.out

I want to update the console progress status by rewriting the same line, but each printing gets in a new line. I'm using Windows 10 pro, Eclipse IDE, Oracle Java 1.8 and source encoding is UTF-8.

My code:

```
String message;
ArrayList<String> fileList = new ArrayList();
fileList.add("file1");
fileList.add("file2");
fileList.add("file3");
for (String fileName : fileList) {
    message = "Procesing file number: " + fileName;
    System.out.print("\r" + message);
}
```

Console output is (3 different lines):

```
Procesing file number: file1
Procesing file number: file2
Procesing file number: file3
```

Why does it System.out.print in a new line as if System.out.println() was used?
I have also tried "Character.toChars(13)" and "(char)13" with the very same outcome.

Comment: Why? Because “that’s how most terminals work” (I quote as that’s what I’ve been told, but I’ve not dived into the reasoning/workings). You could, however, make use of the “backspace” character, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843202/how-to-show-percentage-progress-of-a-downloading-file-in-java-consolewithout-ui/15846788#15846788)

Comment: Try to run the same code not within Eclipse but directly in a CMD window and see if the result is different.

Comment: Eclipse has a setting specifically for that: right-click on the console and select Preferences; or menu Window > Preferences > Run/Debug > Console - last check box: "Interpret Carriage Return (\r) as control character"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [difference between newLine() and carriage return("\r")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307747/difference-between-newline-and-carriage-return-r)

Comment: [Also see the javadoc for System.lineSeparator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator())

Comment: Yes that's not going to work . You're going to need a special library. What you're using is a character from the set of line separators. You were probably thinking of a backspace character but that wouldn't work either as it only works on one character not the whole line, and is anyway not practicable. Console library needed

Answer (score 0):

Solved, thanks to [user16320675](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16320675/user16320675)'s comment:

> Eclipse has a setting specifically for that: right-click on the
> console and select Preferences; or menu Window > Preferences >
> Run/Debug > Console - last check box: "Interpret Carriage Return (\r)
> as control character"

I have upvoted the comment (I cannot mark it as the best solution as it is a comment, not an answer).

Comment: While it's good that you have described a workaround as an answer to your own problem, it doesn't really properly address the actual question that you asked: _"Why does it System.out.print in a new line as if System.out.println() was used?"_